# Printing text in awk conditions

Tags: awk

I would like to print text according some conditions: print lines starting \hello (that works) and I don't know how to add a condition that would wite \a some text \b from this:

```
\item[\word{\small 1}]: \a some text \b
\item[\word{\small 3}]: \a some text \b
```

I look for a condition that would delete the first part of a line that is always same except a number \item[\word{\small 1}]: or a condition that would print text between \a and \b included form the line that included \a and \b.

```
    awk '
/\\hello/
/\\item\[\\word\{\\small ?\}\]\:/{
  next
}
' file.txt
```

file.txt:

```
text
\hello jgfk
4
5
\item[\word{\small 1}]: \a some text \b
\item[\word{\small 3}]: \a some text \b
456465
text
\hello hello
```

desired result:

```
\hello jgfk
\a some text \b
\a some text \b
\hello hello
```

**EDIT**

Case when the code doesn't work:

```
\a
\b
\item[\textcircled{\tiny 1}]: \a \bb \perp \unit{\rho} \Rightarrow \bb \cdot\unit{\rho}=0 \b
```

The output should be:

```
\a \bb \perp \unit{\rho} \Rightarrow \bb \cdot\unit{\rho}=0 \b
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$1=""}1' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/\\hello/; match($0,/\\a.*\\b/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
\hello jgfk
\a some text \b
\a some text \b
\hello hello
```

***Explanation of above code:***

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program here.
/\\hello/                                ##Checking condition if a line has string \hello then by not mentioning any action it will simply print the current line.
match($0,/\\a.*\\b/){                    ##Using match function of awk to match a REGEX where it matches from \\a till \\b of a line, here I have given 2 times \\ to make \ as a a literal character.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)        ##Printing sub-string from value of RSTART till value of RLENGTH, where RSTART and RLENGTH variables will be set when a regex is found by match function.
}                                        ##Closing BLOCK for match function.
' Input_file                             ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***From `man awk` match function's definition:***

> match(s,r) Returns the index of the first longest match  of  regular
>   expression  r  in string s.  Returns 0 if no match.  As a side effect,
>   RSTART is set to the return value.RLENGTH is  set to the length of the
>   match or -1 if no match.  If the empty string is matched, RLENGTH is
>   set to 0,  and  1 is returned if the match is at the front, and
>   length(s)+1 is returned if the match is at the back.
>
> RLENGTH   length  set by the last call to the built-in function,
>   match() RSTART    index set by the last call to match()

Comment: Thank you very much. Could I have a question about inputs that included another \a and \b? I added this example to my question. Is it possible to add condition: it the like stars by \item?

Comment: @Archie, Sure, when I tested my code with your EDIT solution it worked fine for me, lemme know if you have the same results too.

Comment: It works for small codes, but I have no idea why it doesn't work for my not minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good answer from [@RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13), but you can also do it using conditions before your rules and `next`, e.g.

```
awk -F': ' 'NF==2 {print $2; next} $1~/^[\\]/' file
```

Where `-F': '` sets the field separator to `": "` and then `NF==2` checks if you have 2 fields and if so outputs the second field and calls `next` to skip remaining rules and get the next record. The second rule checks whether the first character is `'\'` and if so, prints the record.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`

```
$ awk -F': ' 'NF==2 {print $2; next} $1~/^[\\]/' file
\hello jgfk
\a some text \b
\a some text \b
\hello hello
```

**Note:** if there is the potential that you may have lines with 2 fields that do not start with `'\'` that you don't want to include, you can add the limiting condition to only consider lines beginning with `'\'` for output with:

```
awk -F': ' '$1~/^[\\]/ {if (NF==2) print $2; else print $0}' file
```

(same output)

Comment: Thank you for encouragement sir, you made my day :)

Comment: You are a hard act to follow. I guarantee I learn just as much from you `:)`