# Print text according to conditions with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to print:

parts from \a to \b

parts form \c to \d

when the line stars with \item print from \c to \d

```
    awk '
/\\a|\\c/{
  found=1
}
found;
/\\b|\\d/{
  found=""
}
/\\item/ && match($0,/\\c.*\\d/){
print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}' file.txt
```

file.txt

```
text
\c
fr
6
\d
text
\item text \c apple \d
text
```

the desired output:

```
\c
fr
6
\d
\c apple \d
```

The output now:

```
\c
fr
6
\d
\item text \c apple \d
\c apple \d
```

So the problem is that the line starting \item is also printed. How to solve this please?

Comment: What if line with `\items` are inn between line stats `\c` and starts `\d`?  Here its better you post real life data and not just sample data. Also line with `\c` and `\d` except `\item` line do they only contain `\c` and `\d` or  can it be `my line \c data`, then it should start at `\c` or ignore that line?  Also the backslash messes up `awk`.  If you could use any other symbol, it would help allot, no need all the escaping.

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of your other post here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678476/printing-text-in-awk-conditions and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673004/print-parts-of-file-using-awk

Comment: What if `\c` comes between `\a` and `\b`?

Answer (score 0):

Start printing at `\c` or `\a`.

If `\d` or `\b` print current line, stop printing and `next`.

If line starts with `\item` and has a sequence of `\c` to `\d`, extract the sequence, print it and `next`.

There are many strange inputs for which I don't know what should happen, like ex. when the line with `\item` is found between `\c` and `\d`. Or when a line `\b` is found after `\c`. I ignored such cases.

The following test:

```
awk '
    /^\\item.*\\c.*\\d/{
        sub(/.*\\c/, "\\c", $0)
        sub(/\\d.*/, "\\d", $0)
        print
        next
    }
    /\\c|\\a/,/\\b|\\d/
' <<EOF
text
c
a
\c
fr
6
\d
text
\item text \c apple \d
text
EOF
```

outputs:

```
\c
fr
6
\d
\c apple \d
```

But a `sed` solution looks for me nicer:

```
sed -n '
    /^\\item.*\(\\c.*\\d\).*$/{ s//\1/; p; d; }
    /\\c/,/\\d/p
    /\\a/,/\\b/p
'
```

Comment: Thank you very much and is it possible to combine sed and awk condition for printing file?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's possible to _chain_ `sed` and `awk` programs by feeding output of one program as the input of another, typically by using [the pipe](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) `|` in a shell. I don't understand how is it related to "printing a file". Use `cups` or `lpr` to print things. If you want to save the output to a file, it's typically done by the shell with the help of [redirections](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) `> file`. In [gnu `sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) there is also `-i` option available.

Comment: Thank you and what is wrong with this sed command? `sed 's/\\item\[\\textcircled\{\\tiny ?\}\]\: / /'` that should replace `\item[\textcircled{\tiny 1}]: ` by nothing or one space and there can be other number than 1.

Comment: The `\{` is a beginning of a limiting repetition qauntifier. In basic sed if you want to match `{` or `}`, don't escape it. [regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). Also a dot matches any character, the `?` matches zero or one preceeding character, so ` ?` matches nothing or a space. You want `\\tiny .` I think. Check out [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/).

Comment: So, it is not possible to write that string?